# variable in a loop with iteration

Tags: php, for-loop

I've got multiple variable like : `$variable0`, `$variable1`, `$variable2`.

Is it possible to use them in a loop ?

Example I tried but doesn't work:

```
for($i = 0;$i < 10;$i++){
    $myarray[] = $variable.$i;
}
```

EDIT:

My real variable is : `$game->stats->item0`

and : ${"game->stats->item".$i} doesn't work it tell me : `Undefined variable: game->stats->item0`
The `$` is missing

Thank you.

Comment: btw: this loop will never start running with this condition: `$i > 10`

Comment: I've edited it, just made a typo

Comment: According to your edit, just use: `$game->stats->{"item" . $i}`

Comment: Thanks ! This one work unlike the duplicated one.